# Laravel, wordpress and apache config

Tags: laravel, apache, laravel-routing, apache-config

We have a main site running on laravel and my apache config for that is

```
ServerAdmin admin@test.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/test/public

<Directory /var/www/test/public>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 allow from all
</Directory>
```

We also have blogs on the same domain and the URLs look like
http://test.com/c1/blog
http://test.com/c2/blog

http://test.com runs on Laravel, and so does http://test.com/c1 and http://test.com/c2. Basically, c1 and c2 are pages that are rendered by laravel.

My blog is on wordpress and I have put it under /var/www/c1/blog and /var/www/c2/blog. They are separate instances of Wordpress with separate code and databases. I do not wish to combine them.

How do I set up proper redirection so that the blog pages along with the path is rendered correctly?

I have tried modifying the apache config (i'm sort of new to this), and this is what I have done, which is throwing an internal server error

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/c1/blog
<Directory /var/www/c1/blog>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 allow from all
</Directory>
```

Also tried handling the blog redirects through laravel redirects this way:

```
return File::get(public_path() . '/c1/blog/index.php');
```

and when I go to http://test.com/c1/blog it shows a blank page